# How to convert [4]uint8 into uint32 in Go?

Tags: type-conversion, go

how to convert go's type from uint8 to unit32?
Just code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    uInt8 := []uint8{0,1,2,3}
    var uInt32 uint32
    uInt32 = uint32(uInt8)
    fmt.Printf("%v to %v\n", uInt8, uInt32)
}
```

~>6g test.go && 6l -o test test.6 && ./test 
test.go:10: cannot convert uInt8 (type []uint8) to type uint32

Comment: You didn't specify what you *want*, that's why you get completely different answers. Do you want *one* `uint32` with the value `0x00010203`, *one* `uint32` with the value `0x03020100`, or *four* `uint32`s with the values `{0, 1, 2, 3}`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    u8 := []uint8{0, 1, 2, 3}
    u32LE := binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(u8)
    fmt.Println("little-endian:", u8, "to", u32LE)
    u32BE := binary.BigEndian.Uint32(u8)
    fmt.Println("big-endian:   ", u8, "to", u32BE)
}
```

Output:

```
little-endian: [0 1 2 3] to 50462976
big-endian:    [0 1 2 3] to 66051
```

The Go [binary package](http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/binary/binary.go) functions are implemented as a series of shifts.

```
func (littleEndian) Uint32(b []byte) uint32 {
    return uint32(b[0]) | uint32(b[1])<<8 | uint32(b[2])<<16 | uint32(b[3])<<24
}

func (bigEndian) Uint32(b []byte) uint32 {
    return uint32(b[3]) | uint32(b[2])<<8 | uint32(b[1])<<16 | uint32(b[0])<<24
}
```

Comment: Also worth noting that that if you know that `len(b) >= 4` and don't care about endianness, using `return *(*uint32)(unsafe.Pointer(&b[0]))` is a lot faster.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to the [following](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#convert_slice_of_interface)?

```
t := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
s := make([]interface{}, len(t))
for i, v := range t {
    s[i] = v
}
```

Comment: You are converting `[]int` to `[]interface{}`. That's not what the question asked for.