# Decoding data from a byte slice to Uint32

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
        "bytes"
        "encoding/binary"
        "fmt"
)

func main() {
        aa := uint(0xFFFFFFFF)
        fmt.Println(aa)
        byteNewbuf := []byte{0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF}
        buf := bytes.NewBuffer(byteNewbuf)
        tt, _ := binary.ReadUvarint(buf)
        fmt.Println(tt)
}
```

Need to convert 4 bytes array to uint32 but why the results are not same ? 
go verion : beta 1.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert \[4\]uint8 into uint32 in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380158/how-to-convert-4uint8-into-uint32-in-go)

Answer (score 13):

You can do this with one of the `ByteOrder` objects from the `encoding/binary` package.  For instance:

```
package main

import (
        "encoding/binary"
        "fmt"
)

func main() {
        aa := uint(0x7FFFFFFF)
        fmt.Println(aa)
        slice := []byte{0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x7F}
        tt := binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(slice)
        fmt.Println(tt)
}
```

If your data is in big endian format, you can instead use the same methods on `binary.BigEndian`.

Answer (score 5):

```
tt := uint32(buf[0])<<24 | uint32(buf[1])<<16 | uint32(buf[2]) <<8 |
        uint32(buf[3])
```

for BE or

```
tt := uint32(buf[0]) | uint32(buf[1])<<8 | uint32(buf[2]) <<16 |
        uint32(buf[3]) <<24
```

for LE.

[u]varint is a different kind of encoding (32 bit numbers can have as much as 5 bytes in the encoded form, 64 bit numbers up to 10).

- No need to create a buffer for []byte. Use Varint or Uvarint directly on the byte slice instead.
- You're throwing away the error returned by the function. The second result indicates how many bytes were read or if there was a problem. There **is** a problem while decoding 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff as an uvarint.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to use the [encoding/binary](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Read) package to do what you want.  Note that you don't want to use any of the `var` functions as those do variable length encoding.

[Playground version](http://play.golang.org/p/VDFnYDJe8b)

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    aa := uint(0xFFFFFF0F)
    fmt.Println(aa)
    tt := uint32(0)

    byteNewbuf := []byte{0x0F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF}
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(byteNewbuf)
    err := binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &tt)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Decode failed: %s", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(tt)
}
```

Result is

```
4294967055
4294967055
```

Comment: Wrt the "direct" solution: 1) _much_ more lines 2) _much_ slower 3) generates completely unnecessary garbage to be collected. What's the point?

Comment: The point is showing the OP how to use encoding/binary correctly! For one `uint32` I'd agree with you, but encoding/binary wins for complex data structures, floating point values etc.

Comment: I see no _complex data structures, floating point values etc._ in the OP. I see _"Need to convert 4 bytes array to uint32"_. Doing that via `bytes.Buffer` and `binary.Read`, which takes `interface{}` and uses reflection (sic!) is incredible. (-1)