# Convert `byte` array to `uint32` array

Tags: go

I'd like to use `byte` array as `uint32` array, then get the first element of the uint32 array. But I can not get the following code to work. Could anybody let me know how to cast a `byte` array to a `unit32` array? Thanks.

```
// vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

package main

import (
    "unsafe"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    x := []byte{'\x01', '\x02', '\x03', '\x04', '\x06', '\x07', '\x08', '\x09'}
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", x)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", []int32(unsafe.Pointer(x))[0])
}
```

Comment: What _exactly_ do you need to do? To convert 8 bytes to 2 `uint32`s? What about endianness?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decoding data from a byte slice to Uint32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848830/decoding-data-from-a-byte-slice-to-uint32)

Comment: Endian is the same as the host machine. The link you pointed is not what I am looking for. I want to cast the pointer so that I can directly access the casted array. I don't want to call function to access each element of the uint32.

Comment: Do not use package unsafe. A simple (x[0]<<24)+(x[1]<<16)+(x[2]<<8)+x[3] with proper type conversions or the other way around is good enough.

Comment: @user1424739: you're not accessing the "array" here at all, you're only manipulating the slice header. If you want to access the memory directly, you first have to be pointing at the right memory.

Answer (score 0):

It would be

```
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", (*(*[]int32)(unsafe.Pointer(&x)))[0])
```

but one should remember that it still would have `len = cap = 8` (*), and carefully check for boundaries themselves.

The expression clarification

```
unsafe.Pointer(&x) // an uintptr to an `x` slice

(*[]int32)(...) // a type conversion
                // it's the same syntax when you do float64(42)
                // but in this case you need extra parentheses around the
                // type name to make it unambiguous for the parser
                // so, it converts a unitptr to a pointer to a int32 slice

*(...) // here it's just a pointer dereference. So you obtain a slice
       // from a pointer to a slice, to index it after
```

(*) `cap` is not guaranteed to be `8` in this particular case (but it does not really matter).

Comment: I am confused about the syntax of `(*(*[]int32)(unsafe.Pointer(&x)))`. Could you help me understand how to understand it?

Comment: `(*[]int32)(...)` - this part is a type conversion, the same way like `int(42)`. The `*` in front is dereferencing a pointer.